SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The active result for the query contains no fields occur when using sqlsrv driver but it work fine using dblib driver
When using the sqlsrv driver, apply fetchall() on the SP statement and get error as:

SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The active result for the query has no fields.

But it runs properly when using the dblib driver. Why is that?
code written below
$connection = DB::connection($config['name']);
$pdo = $connection->getPdo();
return $pdo->query($statement)->fetchAll();
and error it return
PDOException {#302  // app/Http/Controllers/SessionController.php:67
#message: "SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The active result for the query contains no fields."
#code: "IMSSP"
#file: "xyz"
#line: 63
errorInfo: array:3
trace: []
}
for this error i got solution as
SET NOCOUNT ON;
and
nextRowSet()
I need the reason for such behaviour I found some answer it run but the reason for those driver I didn't found

When you say "on the SP Statement" do you mean you are executing a stored procedure? Does your procedure start contain SET NOCOUNT ON;?

You need to tag the language your code is written in, because it's a not an SQL Server problem, and therefore SQL server experts can't help you I less they guess the language you are using
